# Copied an existing report in a current solution file and getting the following error

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I copied an existing report and changed a tiny bit. New report keeps showing error message. 
Nothing seems to change but still it is complaining about some group expressions. Dataset is embedded query. Can pointers would be appriciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k691d.jpg)

Comment: Hi. You need to give a little more detail so that people can help you. Perhaps you could try copying the report, check it works, make one change then check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely causes are

1. Your dataset no longer contains a field called `PROJECTID` (this is case sensitive).
2. You have not refreshed the dataset fields (which may cause another error message which will lead you to the actual issue)
3. Your dataset is pointing to a datasource that no longer exists (I think these are also case sensitive) which in turn means the query fails, which means PROJECTID does not exist, hence your error.

Start from the end and work backwards.

- Open the dataset query and execute it or hit Refresh Fields
- If no errors are returned, check that the column `PROJECTID` exists and has the correct case.

This should point you in the right direction.